# can't find Jenkins conf file inside jenkinsci/blueocean container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I am running jenkins blue ocean image. I want to pass startTLS option for jenkins [like](https://emilwypych.com/2017/12/05/jenkins-e-mail-notification-with-office365/?cn-reloaded=1)-

> JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true".

For that I need to edit jenkins conf file. Failed searching at the following locations-
`/etc/defaults/jenkins` and `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` , also, tried searching wildcard like `find / -iname jenkins`, but no luck.
Run jenkins image as-

```
$ docker run \
--rm \
-u root \
-p 8080:8080 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \ 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v "$HOME":/home \ 
jenkinsci/blueocean

$ docker exec -it <image_id> bash
```

Does anyone knows how to edit jenkins conf file here? please let me know if some more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for docker image jenkins/jenkins which is what jenkinsci/blueocean is deriving from.  You can add those options through a JAVA_OPTS environment variable.  So you would do:

```
$ docker run \
--rm \
-u root \
-p 8080:8080 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \ 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v "$HOME":/home \ 
-e JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Here is a link:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md